# Handle token expiration time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in asp net, and i need to ask which is the best way to handle token expiration time.
When i am making a login in my application, i am getting this string.

```
{
"access_token": "pakfbdODTcW9z2uLpVu90DVAhzfKgfYPyxF_6gHI3LbNK4OzrL0RPTUlkgif4WhrQH9yKppjbkyll8Qmi8y_lFkm0NV9bnB0o0Bc2W6Js9oVN8HQZX6FK1j2C_pbrDCL9f47VSJpWSUNLKv5TjUbktHk_StWxrAASJCRjiFqp45hLcJccl2W3xaSl0vYuyhibqboDlPAH55vHuCqGilIEs5eVRH-ZKERaV9xf3qAigr7lF9rPedP5P9CjoxDfU0LJkWYfNuz1PInVGs0mRK2zztlh27Kfkc68tN1B3Ix3aY1JxNu6bjShVESMD_VW_bKU-wFfuA3FSnxVRP3T08pODimd8FaCaHs0HUWwHewgbAMPjeGpySd_3z1lOx657jDLjmXfOahldIhdXGLWykcwdokxYmOzycPoSVYA1LTzx4Nud6YeeW1232HCsE_ZT_O8V5tnwJo0--MdBz2HVvHa08PrBsS96BThLiYPJBidlo",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3599,
"userName": "dimitris22@in.gr",
".issued": "Sat, 15 Dec 2018 20:13:07 GMT",
".expires": "Sat, 15 Dec 2018 21:13:07 GMT"
```

}

My asp net application says that my token will expire after one hour. The problem is that if my client device has wrong hour what will happen there? If my client's device is one hour after or if in mean time client will go and change his device time...
As i understand it is not the safest way to compare asp net expiration time with client's device time.
The second method which seems as solution is to create a timer which it will trigger every one hour.

Is there any tutorial or method i can find?

Comment: Client doesn’t usually really need to care. If it knows it’s expired it can get a new one. If it doesn’t the server will tell it.

Comment: Yes but, how client will now the expiration time? As i can imagine he need to compare it with datetime, right? Or i need to check in every request if server will return (401 Unothorized) to request a new token?

Comment: Yes, you need to handle error situations in any case. The token may expire at any point at the server regardless what it says.

Comment: So 1)making a request and i am taking 401. 2) i request a new token 3) re-run my request. That's the way that things are work?

Comment: Yep, that’s how it works

Comment: In your 401/Unauthorized response you can return either a payload or a response header that conveys "expired token" to the caller.  Be sure to update your API documentation to include your choice.